# Can't get simple Ada Iterator example to compile

Tags: compiler-errors, iterator, ada

I'm learning Ada and I am trying to get a very simple loop working (using the new iterators syntax from Ada 2012).  I cannot see what's wrong...

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Arrays is
  type V is array (0 .. 1, 0 .. 2) of Natural;
  A : V := ((10, 20, 30), (400, 500, 600));
begin
  for E of A loop  --  compiler error here!
    E := E + 1;
  end loop;
end Arrays;
```

My compile command is "$ gnatmake -gnaty -gnaty2 -gnat12 arrays" (for pedantic style enforcement and to enable 2012 features).
The compiler error is

```
arrays.adb:8:14: too few subscripts in array reference
```

(I'm using gnatmake 4.6 on a Raspi).

This code is pieced together from John Barnes' book "Programming in Ada 2012" p.120-121.  I've trimmed down this code as much as I can, that's why it doesn't do much.  As far as I can see, it's effetively identical to the examples in the book.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possibly ... using gcc-4.6. Ada-2012 support has improved a lot since then. gcc-4.9 should be available for the R-Pi and do what you want. (EDIT : gnatmake 4.9 swallows your example silently, making an executable)

Comment: Thank you for investigating that for me.  My raspi seems to think that 4.6 is still the latest version of the gnat tools.  I'll have a hunt around to see if I can manually build 4.9 from sourcecode.

Comment: Raspian is built on Debian, (plus Debian itself is available for the Pi) and 4.9 is standard in Debian Jessie, so depending on your distro it should be available.

Comment: Can't get 4.9 working on my Pi, might hop over to my proper computer and stick a recent Debian distro on there.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: it compiles ok with GNAT 2015 GPL.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, As a test I have installed Debian Jessie on a virtual and can confirm that it does indeed compile this code without complaint.  My next step is to drop this OS onto my netbook so I can do further evaluation of Ada. Thank you very much for this suggestion. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a nested array.

```
    procedure Iterator is
        type rows is array (0 .. 2) of Natural;
        type columns is array (0 .. 1) of rows;
        A : columns := ((10, 20, 30), (400, 500, 600));
    begin
        for column of A loop
            for E of column loop
                E := E + 1;
                put_line (e'img);
            end loop;
        end loop;
    end Iterator;
```